# Backbone: LayoutView needs to listenTo a ItemView inside a CollectionView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, triggers, marionette

I'm trying to use the listenTo method in Backbone to listen to a trigger that is inside a child view, inside a collection view, and up to the collection views parent LayoutView.

From google searches a lot people mentioned to use a library for nested objects in backbone, but I'm trying to work out what the standard way of doing it is.

Just to be clearer, my question is: 
How can I make the trigger in my childView (ItemDetailsView) bubble up to the parent LayoutView (MyItemsList.Layout)

```
      var ItemDetailsView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
          template: JST["items/item"],
          tagName: "li",
          className: "item",

          events: {
              "click @ui.btn": "callTrigger"
          },

          callTrigger: function() {
               this.trigger("hello:world");
           }
      )}; 

      var ItemListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
           tagName: "ul",
           childView: itemDetailsView
       });

      MyItemsList.Layout = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
          template: JST["items/current-items"],
          tagName: "section",
          className: "current-items",

          onShow: function() {
               var listCollection = this.model.currentListCollection;
               var listView = new MyListView({
                    collection: listCollection
               });

               this.listenTo(listView.collection, "hello:world", _.bind(function() {
                    console.log("I heard that!")
               }, this));
          }

       });
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, but you're right that in most cases a library is used.  I tend to think of my objects as more "relational" than "nested" because I started out using backbone-relational (http://backbonerelational.org/) but I stopped using it because I found the API non-intuitive and instead coded my own library to meet my own needs.

Comment: I'v updated my question, hopefully its a bit clearer.  So are you saying there is no standard way to make this work without using a library?  Its just bubbling a trigger up to a parent, it would seem it should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use childEvents property of CollectionView (http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.2/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childevents).

Your code could be then written as follows.

```
  var ItemDetailsView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
      template: JST["items/item"],
      tagName: "li",
      className: "item",

      events: {
          "click @ui.btn": "callTrigger"
      },

      callTrigger: function() {
           this.trigger("hello:world");
       }
  )}; 

  var ItemListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
       tagName: "ul",
       childView: itemDetailsView,
       // This callback will be called whenever a child is rendered or emits a `render` event
       childEvents: {
          "hello:world": function() {
            console.log("a childView said hello world!");
            this.triggerMethod('child:hello:world');
          }
        }
   });

  MyItemsList.Layout = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
      template: JST["items/current-items"],
      tagName: "section",
      className: "current-items",

      onShow: function() {
           var listCollection = this.model.currentListCollection;
           var listView = new MyListView({
                collection: listCollection
           });

           this.listenTo(listView, "child:hello:world", _.bind(function() {
                console.log("I heard that!")
           }, this));
      }

   });
```

Comment: P.R. Ribeiro, this worked for me.  Thanks for the detailed answer. Much appreciated.